# How to make the marker show up on the Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I am trying to get the marker to show up on the google map. I have already been to various SO pages here. Could you please show me the code to make a marker show up on the map?

I have this Javascript:

```
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("latlongdiv");

      if (!navigator.geolocation){
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
      }

      function success(position) {
        var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

        output.appendChild(img);
      };

      function error() {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
      };

      output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating</p>";

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }

    // Function for adding a marker to the page.
        function addMarker(location) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
        }
```

Here is the jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/luwakoburo/edit?html,console,output

Here are the other pages here that I have already checked:

[Add Marker function with Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701077/add-marker-function-with-google-maps-api)

[setting google maps marker javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577089/setting-google-maps-marker-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation for static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro?).  To place a marker on the map, use markers=latitude,longitude.

> **Markers**
>
> The markers parameter defines a set of one or more markers at a set of locations.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/189v5b7g/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("latlongdiv");

  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
geoFindMe();
// Function for adding a marker to the page.
function addMarker(location) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="latlongdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to do this tomorrow. Its midnight here.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! You deserve more reputation here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Change image url to add markers as follows:

img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false&markers=" + latitude + "," + longitude;

Comment: This did not work. I am not a JS kind of guy but I think that semicolon at the end of your example URL should not be there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I assumed you were able to see map and just you were not able to place  marker. So if map was not visible you have to do 3 things to get your code working. (1) Add div in your body <div id="latlongdiv"></div>  (2)call geoFindMe() method. you can add geoFindMe() after addMarker(location) function at end (3) modify image.src url to add    &markers=" + latitude + "," + longitude;                                                Here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/jaganuderu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes, the map was already visible. It just lacked the marker. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In the success callback, you need to generate map and marker object using the longitude and latitude.

The typical procedure is as follows:

1. call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

In the success callback of getCurrentPosition()

2. get a map object with proper location:

   var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

   var mapOptions = {

   zoom: 13,

   center: pos

   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),         mapOptions);
3. generate a marker with the map

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

   map:map,

   position: pos

   });

Here is the good reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: Your example is pretty much just to change "position: latlng", -  to → "position: pos" , is that right?